# Doesn't understand SERQL queries

Tags: api, sesame

i set up a Sesame (openrdf.org) server and try to access it by the Java API.

For test purpose I have used a really simple example from Wikipedia:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework">
 <dc:title>Resource Description Framework</dc:title>
 <dc:publisher>Wikipedia - Die freie Enzyklopädie</dc:publisher>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework">
    <dc:title>Resource Description Framework 2</dc:title>
    <dc:publisher>Wikipedia - Die freie Enzyklopädie</dc:publisher>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The SPARQL query at the Sesame workbench works as expected:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT ?title
WHERE{
?res dc:publisher ?pub .
?res dc:title ?title

FILTER (
sameTerm(?pub, "Wikipedia - Die freie Enzyklopädie")
)
}
```

returns all title from the publisher "Wikipedia - Die freie Enzyklopädie".

Now for the Java API I try to translate this example into SERQL.

I tried following query:

```
SELECT title 
FROM {title} dc:publisher {"Wikipedia - Die freie Enzyklopädie"}
USING NAMESPACE
rdf = <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>,
dc = <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
```

But this returns all data and not the title but the URL from rdf:about. I also tried different variations like "dc:title" instead of "title" but than I get no result at all.

I have already searched the net and read a lot of documentation. But somehow I don't really get the SERQL syntax.

Do you have some pointer for me?
How do I get all title from a specific publisher as a result?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's a complete [SeRQL manual](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch09.html) available in the [Sesame user documentation](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/), so that should help you understand SeRQL's syntax.

As for your specific query, the problem is that your SeRQL query asks something different from the SPARQL query you gave earlier. I won't go into too much detail here, but the SeRQL-equivalent of your SPARQL query would be:

```
SELECT title 
FROM {res} dc:publisher {"Wikipedia - Die freie Enzyklopädie"}; 
           dc:title {title}
USING NAMESPACE
rdf = <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>,
dc = <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
```

SeRQL represents triple-patterns in the form `{subject} predicate {object}` .